# disable bell in pluma editor

Tags: mate, teminal-bell

I'm trying out the Pluma editor in Ubuntu Mate. I like it but cannot find a Preferences option to turn off the bell.

Is this option somewhere else? I don't see a commandline option either.

None of these tries work
here:
https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/07/26/turning-off-the-system-hardware-beep-linux-tutorial/

or here:
https://linuxconfig.org/turn-off-beep-bell-on-linux-terminal

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into sound preferences to turn off all system sounds, just choose the No sound theme.

[image: Sound settings]

Comment: That will also turn off all application sounds

Comment: On Mate 17.10, Pluma 1.18.2 :

Comment: With Mate 17.10, the mute toggle for Alert Volume on the Sound Effects Panel and the mute toggle for Output Volume on the Main Panel have the same effect.  No bell from Pluma, no system sounds.  AND curiouser still, selecting No Sounds disables system sounds but permits the bell in Pluma. From what you say this is not expected behavior.

Comment: Could it be that Pluma is making the sound?

Comment: That must be it.  GEdit (sibling or parent -- what's the term)  has the same behavior and also lacks a Preference option to turn it off. I understand that many people like the feature but enough dislike it to make a good case for an off-switch.